# div's wont align in IE 10 but work fine in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a form that looks like this,[image]

This is how the form should look and it looks perfect in FireFox, my issues is that when I view it in IE 10 it looks like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7unvj/) 
I'm not using a lot of css only that created by the web design software and the one line I added center the divs, which is this

```
#wrapper {
width: 600px;
margin: auto;
}
```

if I had it my way I wouldn't allow it to be viewed in IE but I don't so how can I fix this without breaking it for other browsers?

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't use the web design software. It will be the cause of most of your problems. I don't have IE with me. Chances are that the `input` fields have different `margins` in IE. Since the software seemed to have hardcoded `width` everywhere. I wouldn't be surprised to see things getting messed up because in IE the margins on buttons and `input` are different. Actually the top `div` might have a different calculated `width`. The lower `div` should be good because inputs are way smaller than the containers.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix I only use the software for the initial layout, I manually adjust my field sizes.

Comment: *I'm not using a lot of css*. Well, you should use more. You use in your HTML things like `align="center"`, stacks a lot of `<br>` or even using `&nbsp;`. All these things were outdated ten years ago, at least!

Comment: Seriously there are way too many people that criticize on here instead of helping to find a solution. I didn't ask anybody to nit pick the code or tell me how I should or shouldn't design a web page. I'm not a professional, I don't do this for a living I just want to fix the problem so in the future I'll know what the problem is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing this:-

```
<div id="top" style="float:&quot;left&quot;; width: 286px;" width: "270px" height: "292px">
```

To this:-

```
<div id="top" style="float:left; width: 286px;" width: "270px" height: "292px">
```

Will make it work.

**Updated jsFiddle:-**

http://jsfiddle.net/7unvj/6/

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what the problem was.